# In java if we define a class while creating its object, what is such a class called?

Tags: java

If in java we have a class **A** like in the following code what is the special name for it?

```
public static void main(String args[])
{ obj= new A()
           { ....
           };
}
```

Comment: look at the directory with compiled classes. Anonymous classes contain "$" in their names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an **anonymous inner class**.

Here is a short tutorial regarding these inner classes: http://www.roseindia.net/javatutorials/anonymous_innerclassestutorial.shtml